# How to place marker on one line and get coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, matplotlib

1)I want to place a marker on one line,(between two points) in function of the lenght of the line.

2)I want to know the coordinates of this point/marker.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
x1 = 0
x2 = 9
y1 = 5
y2 = 7
plt.plot((x1, x2), (y1, y2))
lenghtline1 = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
```

Here the distance between the two points is 9.2 ,

How can i put a marker in the line(between the two points) to 6 from point1?

How can i know the coordinates (x,y) of this marker?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point with distance `len` to the first point will have coordinates

```
  x = x1 + (x2-x1) * len / lenghtline1
  y = y1 + (y2-y1) * len / lenghtline1
```

Comment: That worked! than you very much , 
Just to be clear, len is how far you want to put the point in the line , from x1,y1

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import *
from scipy import interpolate

x = rand(21).cumsum() # create some 21 random x values 
y = rand(len(x)) # the corresponding y values
plot(x, y, ".-")
xc = x[:-1]  + diff(x)/2. 
yc = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind="linear")(xc) # (xc, yc) are the marker positions

lengths = sqrt(diff(x)**2 + diff(y)**2) # lengths of the sections
scatter(xc,yc,c=cm.gray(lengths/lengths.max()), s=40) # visualization
show()
```